How to display the HTML tags on the browser <!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, <head>, etc.?
I want to know how to display the html tags on the browser <!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, <head>, etc...
I already used the <pre>,<code>, but it doesn't display on the browser.
I used the apostrophe to show on the browser, but it's kind of wrong.
<pre><'!DOCTYPE html>:</em></b> Declares the document type. "html 5" </pre><br>
    <em><b><'html>:</em></b> Defines the root of an HTML document. <br>
    <em><b><'head>:</em></b> Contains meta-information about the page. <br>
    <em><b><'title>:</em></b> Sets the title of the page. <br>
    <code><em><b><'body>:</em></b> Contains the visible content of the page. <br>
    </code>


This sort of works but the HTML you show is thoroughly invalid. What is the purpose of the apostrophes? Unlike the answers, there is nothing wrong with using <pre> and <code>

I think you are talking about character entities
< can be displayed with &lt;
> can be displayed with &gt;

Example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

Here it goes &lt;html&gt;
    
</body>
</html>



You can find a list of character entities here

No. That's not what he's asking about.

As Emre Kanbay already explained in his answer here, you should be using the &lt; and &gt; character entities. You can actually get away with writing the closing > as such (see the first line in my snippet) but it is considered to be bad style as it can easily turn into something else: the closing of an element's tag.
However, if you really want to go with a special character after the < you can use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space: &#8203;.


<em><b>&lt;!DOCTYPE html>:</em></b> Declares the document type. "html 5"<br> 
<em><b>&lt;html&gt;:</em></b> Defines the root of an HTML document. <br>
<em><b><&#8203;head>:</em></b> Contains meta-information about the page. <br>
<em><b><&#8203;title>:</em></b> Sets the title of the page. <br>
<em><b><&#8203;body>:</em></b>Contains the visible content of the page. <br>




No. That's not what he's asking about.
